# Some clarifications needed about the Vaught Tarski Test

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'll leave the question here in case someone else had an issue. The variables of the formulas are evaluated in $M$. Clarifies everything!

From my understanding of the Vaught Tarsi test, it states the following:
Suppose $M\subseteq N$ is a substructure of $N$. Then $M \preceq N$ (i.e. a formula is true in $M$ if and only if it is true in $N$) if and only if for all formulas $\varphi$ of the form $\varphi = \exists x \psi$,
            $$
    N \vDash \varphi \implies \text{ there exists } a \in M \textit{ such that } N \vDash \psi(a)
   $$
The general proof is inductive. But my confusion is about the universal quantifier. If a formula is of the form $\forall\psi$ then couldn't it be true in $M$ without being true in $N$?

I am a beginner and possibly misunderstanding this a lot, so any explanation is welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close - this seems perfectly clear to me . . .

Comment: The vote to close reflects one moment in time in the history of this question. It's still not really clear what a question that now includes "Clarifies everything!" in the first paragraph is actually about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any formula is equivalent to a formula with only existential quantifiers, since you can replace every quantifier $\forall x$ with $\neg\exists x \neg$.  So in proving $M\preceq N$, you can consider only formulas without universal quantifiers.

Another way to think about what's going on is that if $\forall x:\varphi(x)$ were not true in $N$, then that means $\exists x:\neg\varphi(x)$ is true in $N$.  By the assumption, this existential statement must have a witness in $M$.  As a result, $\forall x:\varphi(x)$ will end up being false in $M$ as well.